# Bounded linear transformation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is about the  [BLT theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension).

Tell me please, how we can extend a bounded linear transformation from normed space **X** to blt from completion of **X**, if we dont prove that comletion of **X** is *vector* space. For me its not obvious that completion of **X** is *normed vector* spase just because the dense subset **X** is vector space. So, do we need in this theorem to prove firstly that completion of **X** is normed vector spase, and if so, how to prove it?

Comment: The completion is a normed space by definition. It is a Banach space which contains a dense subspace which is isometric to $X$. This is the definition of completion that I know.

Comment: @Mark Why the completion is normed space by definition? The completion of normed vector spase is its completion as a metric space with a metric generated by the norm. If this completion is Banach space, i.e. complete normed *vector* space, we can somehow prove this statement, cant we?

Comment: I guess you are using a different definition of completion. Well, then you can just define sum and scalar multiplication of Cauchy sequences, right? Just define it term by term, using the fact that you have these operations in $X$. So that way the completion will be a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one needs to first show that the completion is a complete normed space. That depends on how you define the completion of a metric space. Since completions are essentially unique, it doesn't really matter, so let's take the completion to be the complete metric space $\tilde{X}$ of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with distance (well-defined) $$d((x_n),(y_n)):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n-y_n\|.$$
Then to extend the addition and scalar multiplication of $X$ to $\tilde{X}$, define $$(x_n)+(y_n):=(x_n+y_n)$$ $$\lambda(x_n):=(\lambda x_n)$$ $$\|(x_n)\|:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|$$ You would need to check that these are all well-defined, i.e. depend only on the equivalence classes. Then check that they satisfy the axioms of addition, scalar multiplication, and norms. Finally, since the norm is induced by the complete metric, $d((x_n),(y_n))=\|(x_n)-(y_n)\|$, that means that the normed space is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Why the completion is normed space by definition? The completion of normed vector spase is its completion as a metric space with a metric generated by the norm. If this completion is Banach space, i.e. complete normed *vector* space, we can somehow prove this statement, cant we?